# In chrome.tabs.query and chrome.tabs.getcurrent, the tabs length is coming as zero

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to remove the tab using the tabid using the chrome extension.

I have tried getting the current tab using chrome.tabs.getcurrent and chrome.tabs.query api  both of them did not work for me.

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true ,currentwindow: true}, function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
            });
```

and

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
                chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
            });
```

Expected result : need to remove the current tab from chrome.
Actual result : tabs length is coming as 0.

Comment: Use query(), but currentwindow should be currentWindow, tab.id should be tab[0].id, however getCurrent() is an entirely different thing, not useful in your case.

Comment: correct. But, I need to remove the tab I have tried the the query correctly but still the length is zero for query.
below is my code,
 var query = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
       chrome.tabs.query(query, function (tabArray) {
                chrome.tabs.remove(tabArray.id);
            });

Comment: It's still incorrect. Use tabArray[0].id

Comment: That is fine I have changed it. But my problem here is tabArray itself is coming as empty.

Comment: You probably have a devtools window active. Close it.

Comment: Thanks for your response let me try after closing the devtools.